# JavaFX TextFieldListCell customize label display

Tags: listview, javafx, cell

I need to show a customized label in a TextFieldListCell and I wrote this:

```
setEditable(true);
setCellFactory(TextFieldCell.forListView());
class TextFieldCell extends TextFieldListCell<String>{
@Override
public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
    super.updateItem(item, empty);
    setText(item == null ? "" : "<value to insert> " +item);

}   }
```

My idea is to show a editable cell like this

when no editing (label)
        < variable> "value"

when editing (textfield)
        "value"

where "value" represents the proper value of the item, and < variable> a specific string for each item, concatenated with the "value".

How can I do this?

Comment: and your question is?

Comment: I added the question. Thanks!